# Swift: Cannot convert Type<Subtype> to Type<Any>

Tags: swift, apollo, apollo-ios

I am looking to create a function to handle potential errors in GraphQL mutation results, using the Apollo SDK. Apollo can have errors as part of its success data.

To keep it as generic as possible, I define my function as:

```
    func alertResult(result: Result<GraphQLResult<Any>, Error>) {
        print(result)
        switch result {
        case let .failure(error):
            self.presentAlert(title: "Operation Error", message: "API says: \(error)")
        case let .success(data):
            if let errors = data.errors {
                self.presentAlert(title: "Operation Error", message: "API says: \(errors)")
            }
        }
    }
```

When used with a specific Apollo mutation, `InviteToCommunityMutation`, the compiler rejects it with the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Result<GraphQLResult<InviteToCommunityMutation.Data>, any Error>' to expected argument type 'Result<GraphQLResult<Any>, any Error>'
```

I find this bizarre, as surely `InviteToCommunityMutation.Data` should be convertible to `Any`.

If I try to define my function more broadly with:

```
func alertResult(result: Result<Any, Error>)
```

then I get `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` when trying to extract `data.errors` from `.success(data)`.

Would love help! Also, I'm new to Stackoverflow, so tried to include only relevant data but happy to provide more.

Comment: Try `func alertResult<T>(result: Result<GraphQLResult<T>, Error>) {`

Comment: Thanks - it works! Can you tell me why the Any conversion didn't work and how this solves it, or tell me where in the docs I can understand what you're doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your function generic:

```
func alertResult<T>(result: Result<GraphQLResult<T>, Error>) {
```

By using `T` as a generic placeholder type, you allow Swift to synthesize an appropriate function for any subtype of `GraphQLResult`.

You can read about Swift Generics [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html).

Note: The error message tells you why `Any` doesn’t work.  `Result<GraphQLResult<InviteToCommunityMutation.Data>, any Error>` and  `Result<GraphQLResult<Any>, any Error>` are two different types.  Generics allow Swift to generate a function with the properly matching type.